# Android [Android Studio] How to use PlayerSDK from Hikvision CCTV SDK

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to use Player SDK from Hikvision CCTV on my android project.
http://www.hikvision.com/europe/download_more.asp?id=1333 
I already tried to import the PlayerSDK.jar file on my libs folder (I'm using android studio IDE), I don't have any idea on how to configuring to able to livestream online CCTVs from android devices.

Comment: where to get this library from. The url you have given is not working for me

Comment: Which Hikvision library you used to implement cctv? I am also facing same issue. Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This SDK for play HIK local video files or video stream.
Simple usage:

```
import org.MediaPlayer.PlayM4.Player;

....

Player hik = Player.getInstance();
...
int sv = hik.getSdkVersion();
int hport = hik.getPort();
```

Read SDK attached with library.
Basic SDK commands sequence to play video stream:

```
getPort
setStreamOpenMode
openStream
Play
inputData
stop
closeStream
freePort
```

To connect HIK device and get video stream from cameras you need to use HCNetSDK library.
I don't found on HIK site this library for android but I think its possible to compile unix version for android.

Comment: Which Hikvision library shall I use to implement cctv in android application?